# Как растянуть текстуру на весь 3D объект?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Есть картинка, которую надо растянуть на весь 3D объект, сейчас это выглядит так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должна выглядеть вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это main.cpp:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <C:\Users\robert\Desktop\slot\slot\stb_image.h>
#include <C:\Users\robert\Desktop\slot\slot\include\glm\glm.hpp>
#include <C:\Users\robert\Desktop\slot\slot\include\glm\gtc\matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <C:\Users\robert\Desktop\slot\slot\include\glm\gtc\type_ptr.hpp>
#include <C:\Users\robert\Desktop\slot\slot\shader.h>

#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // configure global opengl state
    // -----------------------------
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // build and compile our shader zprogram
    // ------------------------------------
    Shader ourShader("C:/Users/robert/Desktop/slot/slot/6.2.coordinate_systems.vs", "C:/Users/robert/Desktop/slot/slot/6.2.coordinate_systems.fs");
    Shader ourShader1("C:/Users/robert/Desktop/slot/slot/6.2.coordinate_systems.vs", "C:/Users/robert/Desktop/slot/slot/6.2.coordinate_systems.fs");
    Shader ourShader2("C:/Users/robert/Desktop/slot/slot/6.2.coordinate_systems.vs", "C:/Users/robert/Desktop/slot/slot/6.2.coordinate_systems.fs");


    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float vertices[] = {

         0.25f, -0.5f, 0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.25f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.0f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.0f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.0f, 0.5f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.25f, -0.5f, 0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

         0.5f,  0.0f, 0.5f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.0f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.25f, 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.25f, 0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.25f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.0f, 0.5f,   0.0f, 1.0f,

         -0.25f, 0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         -0.25f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         -0.5f,  0.0f, -0.5f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
         -0.25f, 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,

         -0.5f,  0.0f, -0.5f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
         -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         -0.25f, -0.5f, 0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         -0.25f, -0.5f, 0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         -0.25f, -0.5f, -0.5f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
         -0.5f,  0.0f, -0.5f,   0.0f, 1.0f,

        -0.25f, 0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.25f,  0.5f, 0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.25f,  0.5f,  -0.5f,  .0f, 1.0f,
         0.25f,  0.5f,  -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.25f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         -0.25f,  0.5f, 0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,

         0.25f, -0.5f, 0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.25f,  -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         -0.25f,  -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         -0.25f,  -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         -0.25f,  -0.5f,  -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.25f,  -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    unsigned int VBO[3], VAO[3];
    glGenVertexArrays(3, VAO);
    glGenBuffers(3, VBO);




    glBindVertexArray(VAO[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO[1]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO[2]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[2]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);




    unsigned int texture1;




    glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
    // set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true); // tell stb_image.h to flip loaded texture's on the y-axis.
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load("C:/Users/robert/Desktop/slot/slot/Pattern01.png", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

    float angle = 90.0f * 1;


    glm::vec3 cubePositions[] = {
        glm::vec3(1.5f, 0.f, -3.0f),
        glm::vec3(.0f, .0f, -3.0f),
        glm::vec3(-1.5f, 0.f, -3.0f),
    };

    int cubeRotations[] = {
      3, 4, 200
    };


    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.7f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // also clear the depth buffer now!



        // activate shader
        ourShader.use();

        // create transformations
        glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f); // make sure to initialize matrix to identity matrix first
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        glm::mat4 trans = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        trans = glm::scale(trans, glm::vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
        projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        // pass transformation matrices to the shader
        ourShader.setMat4("projection", projection); // note: currently we set the projection matrix each frame, but since the projection matrix rarely changes it's often best practice to set it outside the main loop only once.
        ourShader.setMat4("view", view);
        ourShader.setMat4("transform", trans);

        // render boxes
        glBindVertexArray(VAO[0]);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            // calculate the model matrix for each object and pass it to shader before drawing
            glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);

            model = glm::translate(model, cubePositions[i]);
            model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(angle), glm::vec3(0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f));
            model = glm::rotate(model, (float)glfwGetTime() * cubeRotations[i], glm::vec3(0.0f, .0f, 1.0f));
            ourShader.setMat4("model", model);

            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        }

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays(3, VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(3, VBO);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Это shader.h:

```
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class Shader
{
public:
    unsigned int ID;
    // constructor generates the shader on the fly
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Shader(const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath)
    {
        // 1. retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
        std::string vertexCode;
        std::string fragmentCode;
        std::ifstream vShaderFile;
        std::ifstream fShaderFile;
        // ensure ifstream objects can throw exceptions:
        vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        fShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        try
        {
            // open files
            vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
            fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
            std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
            // read file's buffer contents into streams
            vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
            fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();
            // close file handlers
            vShaderFile.close();
            fShaderFile.close();
            // convert stream into string
            vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
            fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
        }
        catch (std::ifstream::failure& e)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
        const char* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
        const char* fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();
        // 2. compile shaders
        unsigned int vertex, fragment;
        // vertex shader
        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex);
        checkCompileErrors(vertex, "VERTEX");
        // fragment Shader
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment);
        checkCompileErrors(fragment, "FRAGMENT");
        // shader Program
        ID = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(ID, vertex);
        glAttachShader(ID, fragment);
        glLinkProgram(ID);
        checkCompileErrors(ID, "PROGRAM");
        // delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessery
        glDeleteShader(vertex);
        glDeleteShader(fragment);

    }
    // activate the shader
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void use() const
    {
        glUseProgram(ID);
    }
    // utility uniform functions
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setBool(const std::string& name, bool value) const
    {
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), (int)value);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setInt(const std::string& name, int value) const
    {
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setFloat(const std::string& name, float value) const
    {
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec2(const std::string& name, const glm::vec2& value) const
    {
        glUniform2fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]);
    }
    void setVec2(const std::string& name, float x, float y) const
    {
        glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec3(const std::string& name, const glm::vec3& value) const
    {
        glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]);
    }
    void setVec3(const std::string& name, float x, float y, float z) const
    {
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y, z);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec4(const std::string& name, const glm::vec4& value) const
    {
        glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]);
    }
    void setVec4(const std::string& name, float x, float y, float z, float w) const
    {
        glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y, z, w);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setMat2(const std::string& name, const glm::mat2& mat) const
    {
        glUniformMatrix2fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setMat3(const std::string& name, const glm::mat3& mat) const
    {
        glUniformMatrix3fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setMat4(const std::string& name, const glm::mat4& mat) const
    {
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
    }

private:
    // utility function for checking shader compilation/linking errors.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void checkCompileErrors(GLuint shader, std::string type)
    {
        GLint success;
        GLchar infoLog[1024];
        if (type != "PROGRAM")
        {
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
            if (!success)
            {
                glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER_COMPILATION_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
            if (!success)
            {
                glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM_LINKING_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
};
#endif
```

6.2 vs

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = transform * projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, 1.0 - aTexCoord.y);
}
```

6.2 fs

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoord;

// texture samplers
uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D texture2;

void main()
{
    // linearly interpolate between both textures (80% container, 20% awesomeface)
    FragColor = mix(texture(texture1, TexCoord), texture(texture2, TexCoord), 0.2);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где-то у вас съехали текстурные координаты. На беглый взгляд ошибок в коде с ними не видно. Занимайтесь отладкой.

Comment: Текстурные координаты `v` для каждой грани должны иметь шаг 1/6

Comment: @user7860670 не особо понял, можете дать массив с координатами?